# iPad specific CSS Div issue

Tags: css, ipad, html

I have an issue regarding a div we have on our test site, only when viewed on an iPad (or, I'm guessing, a screen that is tablet size)...

http://jmldirect.uat.venda.com

The Join Us (social icons) // Newsletter bar bleeds out of the main wrapper and I have no idea why.

Here is the HTML and relevant CSS:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="socialfooter">
<ul class="getSocial">
    <li><a class="join-us">JOIN US</a></li>
    <li><a class="foot-fb" href="https://www.facebook.com/JMLDirect" target="_blank" alt="JML on Facebook"></a></li>  
    <li><a class="foot-tw" href="https://twitter.com/JML_Direct" target="_blank" alt="JML on Twitter"></a></li>
    <li><a class="foot-yt" href="http://www.youtube.com/user/JMLdirect" target="_blank" alt="JMl's YouTube Channel"></a></li>
</ul>


<ul class="newsletter">
<li><label for="emailsignup"><a class="join-us">SIGN UP TO OUR NEWSLETTER</a></label></li>
<li><form></form></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#socialfooter {
    background: url("../images/social_icons/social_footer_wrapper_1010.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    height: 55px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1010px;
}

#socialfooter ul.getSocial {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 7px 0 0 46px;
    width: 192px;
}

#socialfooter ul.newsletter {
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    height: 38px;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 7px 11px 9px 0;
    width: 564px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ANSWER:**

**1. Markup:**

```
<div class=“socialfooter”>
<ul class="getSocial">
    <li><a class="join-us">JOIN US</a></li>
    <li><a class="foot-fb" href="https://www.facebook.com/JMLDirect" target="_blank" alt="JML on Facebook"></a></li>  
    <li><a class="foot-tw" href="https://twitter.com/JML_Direct" target="_blank" alt="JML on Twitter"></a></li>
    <li><a class="foot-yt" href="http://www.youtube.com/user/JMLdirect" target="_blank" alt="JMl's YouTube Channel"></a></li>
    <li><a class="foot-pin" href="http://www.pinterest.com/JMLdirect" target="_blank" alt="JMl on Pinterest"></a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="cards">
    <li><a class="mastercard"></a></li>
    <li><a class="visa"></a></li>
    <li><a class="maestro"></a></li>
    <li><a class="visaElectron"></a></li>
    <li><a class="Paypal"></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**2. CSS:**

```
.socialfooter {
height:55px;
width:100%;
background:url("../images/social_icons/social_footer_wrapper_1010.png") repeat-y 50% 0 transparent;
clear:both;
position:relative;
}

.socialfooter ul.getSocial {
display:inline-block;
box-sizing: border-box;
float:left;
list-style-type:none;
margin:.5em 0 0 -38em;
width:30%;
position:absolute;
}

.getSocial li {
position:relative;
float:left;
}

.socialfooter ul.cards {
display: inline-block;
float: right;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 1.35em 0 0 13em;
position: absolute;
width: 30%;
}

.socialfooter li {
display: inline-block;
list-style-type: none;
background:none;
}

.cards li {
float:left;
padding:0 7px;
}

.cards li a {
background: url("../images/social_icons/elements.png") no-repeat transparent;
}

.cards li a.mastercard {
    background-position: -15px -385px;
    display: block;
    height: 24px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    width: 38px;
}

.cards li a.visa {
    background-position: -58px -386px;
    display: block;
    height: 24px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    width: 38px;
}

.cards li a.maestro {
    background-position: -102px -385px;
    display: block;
    height: 24px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    width: 38px;
}

.cards li a.visaElectron {
    background-position: -145px -385px;
    display: block;
    height: 24px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    width: 38px;
}

.cards li a.Paypal {
    background-position: -189px -385px;
    display: block;
    height: 24px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    width: 38px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set a width on the parent div:

```
#socialfooter{ width:1010px;}
```

and then floated the newsletter ul to the right of that div:

```
#socialfooter ul.newsletter{float:right; width:564px;}
```

The problem with this is that the iPad doesn't have the resolution to display such a wide div (#socialfooter).

If you want the content to show up, use percentage based widths like this:

```
#socialfooter {
    background: url("../images/social_icons/social_footer_wrapper_1010.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    height: 55px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}

#socialfooter ul.getSocial {
    display:inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float:left;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:.5em 0 0 2em;
    width:50%;
}

#socialfoter ul.newsletter {
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float:right;
    vertical-align: middle;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding:0 2em 0 0;
    width:50%;
}
```

EDIT:

```
#socialfooter {
    background: url("../images/social_icons/social_footer_wrapper_1010.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent; //
```

^ This background is causing the issue. It is an image that is set to 1010px, so even CSS isn't going to help you there.

```
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    height: 55px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}

#socialfooter ul.getSocial {
    display:inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float:left;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:.5em 0 0 2em;
    width:30%;
}
```

^ Changed the width to accommodate the large input field on the right side

```
#socialfoter ul.newsletter {
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float:right;
    vertical-align: middle;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding:0 2em 0 0;
    width:70%;
}
```

^ And gave this right side more width to make room for your input.

Comment: Thank you for this Jonathan, but if I put the width of the ID div to 100%, it spans the entire body width, when I need it to be in the wrapper. Your code also throws the elements out when  zooming in and out.

Comment: I am not seeing a wrapper in the code example you provided. Can you provide the complete code?

Comment: I edited my code above to reflect what I saw when I fired up the iOS simulator. Long story short, with the above code, the issue will be fixed if you change (remove) the background image on that social footer. Overall, your site is not responsive, and this is just one of the many issues you are going to encounter if you want to support tablets and mobile devices.